# what is the difference between user mode and kernel mode in terms of total number of machine instructions available?

Tags: operating-system

I read this paragraph from " *Modern Operating Systems , Tanenbaum* "

**Most computers have two modes of operation: kernel
mode and user mode. The operating system is the most fundamental piece of software and runs in kernel mode (also called supervisor mode). In this mode it has complete access to all the hardware and can execute any instruction the machine is capable of executing. The rest of the software runs in user mode, in which only a subset of the machine instructions is available.**

I am unable to get how they are describing difference in these two modes on basis of machine instructions available , at user end  any software has the capability to make any changes at the hardware level ,like we have software which can affect the functioning of CPU , can play with registry details , so how can we say that at user mode , we have only subset of machine instructions available ?

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions that are available only in kernel mode are tend to be very few. These instructions are those that are only needed to manage the system.

For example, most processors have a HALT instruction that stops the CPU that is used for system shutdowns. Obviously you would not want any user to be able to execute HALT and stop the computer for everyone. Such instructions are then made only accessible in kernel mode.

Processors use a table of handlers for interrupt and exceptions. The Operating system creates such a table listing the handlers for these events. Then it loads register(s) giving the location(and size) of the table. The instructions for loading this register(s) are kernel mode only. Otherwise, any application could create total havoc on the system.

Instructions of these nature will trigger an exception if executing in user mode.

Such instructions tend to be few in number.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in `user-mode`, there is definitely a subset of instructions available. This is the reason we have [System Calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

**Example:**

A user wants to create a new process in C. He cannot do that without entering `kernel-mode`, because certain set of instructions are only available to `kernel-mode`, So he uses the `system call` `fork`, that executes instructions for creating a new process (not available in `user-mode`). So `System call` is a mechanism of requesting a service from `kernel` of the `OS` to do something for the user, which he/she cannot write code for.

Following excerpt from above link sums it up in the best way:

> A program is usually limited to its own address space so that it
>   cannot access or modify other running programs or the operating system
>   itself, and is usually prevented from directly manipulating hardware
>   devices (e.g. the frame buffer or network devices).
>
> However, many normal applications obviously need access to these
>   components, so system calls are made available by the operating system
>   to provide well defined, safe implementations for such operations. The
>   operating system executes at the highest level of privilege, and
>   allows applications to request services via system calls, which are
>   often initiated via interrupts. An interrupt automatically puts the
>   CPU into some elevated privilege level, and then passes control to the
>   kernel, which determines whether the calling program should be granted
>   the requested service. If the service is granted, the kernel executes
>   a specific set of instructions over which the calling program has no
>   direct control, returns the privilege level to that of the calling
>   program, and then returns control to the calling program.